# DNSmasq - Server Cache Snooping Remote Information Disclosure

Tags: linux, security, dnsmasq

I am seeing the following vulnerability on my open/public WiFi.

> "DNSmasq - Server Cache Snooping Remote Information Disclosure"

This is a Linux box that serves Internet access to customers and I use `dnsmasq` as DNS server. How can I mitigate this vulnerability? I can't see any reasonable solution online.

**NOTE:** This issue is being flagged from a Nessus security scan. The vulnerability is mentioned here: https://www.tenable.com/plugins/nessus/12217.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you just need to update to this version of `dnsmasq`:

> *version 2.79*
>
> Fix parsing of CNAME arguments, which are confused by extra spaces.
>       Thanks to Diego Aguirre for spotting the bug.
>
> Where available, use IP_UNICAST_IF or IPV6_UNICAST_IF to bind
>       upstream servers to an interface, rather than SO_BINDTODEVICE.
>       Thanks to Beniamino Galvani for the patch.
>
> Always return a SERVFAIL answer to DNS queries without the
>       recursion desired bit set, UNLESS acting as an authoritative
>       DNS server. This avoids a potential route to cache snooping.

The last paragraph covers it.

#### References

- [dnsmasq CHANGELOG](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/CHANGELOG)